# Suggestion for adding a timebomb/license for a video file for offline distribution?

Tags: authentication, video

Can you suggest for adding a timebomb/license for a copyright video file? Like it could be embedding a piece of code in video file which checks for expiry.  It is required  to do offline distribution of video file and needto be made accessible for a certain period of time.

Comment: If you just send a playable file it will always be playable cos the file is itself the picture & sound... Only thing I can think of is to a provide customised player software that has the checking logic included. So the (video) file bytes would be modified in such a way that it has expiry date and you also mix-up (specific) random bytes so that only the program reverses the mix-up and now can decodes video as usual (bytes are now valid frames) if within expiry date.

Answer (score 0):

Most DRM systems now support persistent licenses to allow 'download and go' functionality.

When the client requests a DRM license the metadata with the license key includes information on whether the license is persistent or not and how long it can persist for.

The content owner can set the policies in the license server to be different for different content and even for different users.